# How to Implement Loose Coupling with a SOA Architecture

Tags: c#, soa, esb, loose-coupling

I've been doing a lot of research lately about SOA and ESB's etc.

I'm working on redesigning some legacy systems at work now and would like to build it with more of a SOA architecture than it currently has. We use these services in about 5 of our websites and one of the biggest problems we have right now with our legacy system is that almost all the time when we make bug fixes or updates we need to re-deploy our 5 websites which can be a quite time consuming process.

My goal is to make the interfaces between services loosely coupled so that changes can be made without having to re-deploy all the dependent services and websites.

I need the ability to extend an already existing service interface without breaking or updating any of its dependencies. Have any of you encountered this problem before? How did you solve it?

Comment: Hello Brian, +1 good question. I would like to learn too. Could you please update this question with the online resources you found bit useful for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest looking at a different style of services than maybe you've been doing so far. Consider services that collaborate with each other using events, rather than request/response. I've been using this approach for many years with clients in various verticals with a great deal of success. I've written up quite a bit about these topics in the past 4 years. Here's one place where you can get started:

http://www.udidahan.com/2006/08/28/podcast-business-and-autonomous-components-in-soa/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I never thought of that. Its funny because I downloaded a copy of your open source ESB nServiceBus about a week ago. Only browsed the code for about an hour and I assumed that what you were doing wouldn't solve my problem. 

I saw a bunch of classes that were being passed around between the publishers / subscribers and it made me think that any changes would cause any dependencies to be rebuilt. After reading what you posted it all makes sense. They're passing individual messages around through events not the entire service interface. I can add new messages without breaking any existing code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches you can take.  Our SOA architecture involves XML messages sent to and from the services.  One way we achieve what you describe is by avoiding the use of a data binding library to our XML schema and use a generic XML parser to get just the data nodes you want ignoring those you aren't interested in.  This way the service can add additional new nodes to the message without breaking anyone currently using it.  We typically only do this when we need just one or two pieces of information from a larger schema structure.

Alternatively, the other (preferred) solution we use is versioning. A version of a service adheres to a particular schema/interface.  When the schema changes (e.g the interface is extended or modified), we create a new version of the service.  At any time we may have 2 or 3 versions on the go at any one time.  In time, we deprecate and then remove older versions, while eventually migrating dependent code onto newer versions.  This way those dependent on the service can continue using the existing version of the service while some particular dependency can 'upgrade' to the new version.  Which versions of a service are called are defined in a configuration file for the dependent code.  Note that it is not only the schema which gets versioned, but all of the underlying implementation code as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this defiantly is one solution that would work too. However I think the biggest problem I had wrapping my head around all this was that when I thought about a service I was thinking that it requires a service contract much like the one used in WCF Services. When you break it down and turn each API function into its own message solving this problem becomes much easier. Because you can add as many messages as you want to the service you can now add aditional versions and new messages to the service.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't an easy topic. There are many ways you can go about making your Service Oriented Architecture loosely coupled.

I suggest checking out Thomas Erl's [SOA book series](http://www.soabooks.com/). It explains everything pretty clearly and in-depth.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I know that this is not a easy topic. I've been researching it for the past month it seems. I've watched a few presentations on InfoQ also looked a few books online so i have a pretty good understanding of what the end product needs to look like but having a hard time getting from point A to point B. I'll take a look at the book you suggested maybe it will help clear things up a little.

Comment: Justin, by any chance are you aware of any online resources throwing some light on this partucular question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few common pratices to achieve loose coupling for services.

1. Use doc/literal style of web services, think in data (the wire format) instead of RPC, avoid schema-based data binding.
2. Abide strictly by the contract when sending out data, but keep few assumptions processing incoming data, xpath is a good tool for that (loose in, tight out)
3. Use ESB and avoid any directly point to point communication between services.

Comment: Yeah i decided to use an ESB NServiceBus. It seems to have solved most of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough checklist for evaluating whether your SOA implements Loose Coupling:

- **Location of the called system (its physical address):** Does your
  application use direct URLs for accessing systems or is the
  application decoupled via an abstraction layer that is responsible
  for maintaining connections between systems? The Services Registry
  and the service group paradigm used in SAP NetWeaver CE are good
  examples of what such an abstraction might look like. Using an
  enterprise service bus (ESB) is another example. The point is that
  the application should not hard code the physical address of the
  called system in order to truly be considered loosely coupled.
- **Number of receivers:** Does the application specify which systems are
  the receivers of a service call? A loosely coupled composite will not
  specify particular systems but will leave the delivery of its
  messages to a service contract implementation layer. A tightly
  coupled application will explicitly call the receiving systems in
  order; a loosely coupled application simply makes calls to the
  service interface and allows the service contract implementation
  layer to take care of the details of delivering messages to the right
  systems.
- **Availability of systems:** Does your application require that all the
  systems that you are connecting to be up and running all the time?
  Obviously, this is a very difficult requirement especially if you
  want to connect to external systems that are not under your control.
  If the answer is that all systems must be running all the time, the
  application is tightly coupled in this regard.
- **Data format:** Does the application reuse the data formats provided by
  the backend systems or are you using a canonical data type system
  that is independent of the type systems used in the called
  applications? If you are reusing the data types of the backend
  systems, you probably have to struggle with data type conversions in
  your application, and this is not a very loosely coupled approach.
- **Response time:** Does the application require called systems to respond
  within a certain timeframe or is it acceptable for the application to
  receive an answer minutes, hours, or even days later?